# Android MVP application

Tags: android, mvp, mosby

I'm going to start a new android project, and I want to use clean architecture and MVP. I've been reading about this, and I've found the Mosby library, however, which are the benefits of using the Mosby library instead of using MVP without Mosby? How are you implementing the MVP?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I wrote my own library for implementing MVP, but in using any library, situations might arise where you must rely on your own understanding of MVP to make adjustments, so get ready for that before using any library. You might want to read my article on this here: http://www.digigene.com/mvp-easymvp-wolfkcats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically your question is: Should I use a library or not?

So why are you using libraries at all? Because you don't write the code by your own, and over and over again, right? So Mosby and Nucleus are just two libraries so that you don't have to write your MVP template by your own. Also they can handle screen orientation changes and process death for you.

But basically, yes, you can write it all by your own. Actually it's not that hard (except screen orientation changes and process death handling).